# How to check if connection is the performance bottleneck

Tags: java, performance, tcp, connection, ignite

I am using Apache Ignite with a Java application and observing that with increasing concurrency, response times also increases.  I noticed that there is only one connection established between the java application and the Ignite server. How can I confirm if that is the bottleneck? Thread dumps reveal that some threads are waiting for the `Socket.Read` method. Is it relatable to number of connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Ignite 2.7.6, [Thin Client](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/thin-clients) establishes only one connection to the server node. Yes, it can become a bottleneck when used from multiple threads.

I can recommend either having one `IgniteClient` instance per thread, or using some kind of a connection pool.

Also, Ignite 2.8 introduces Partition Awareness (release is planned for today), where thin client connection is established to every specified server node, and key-based requests are dispatched to primary nodes. This may help in your case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the applications that comes with the java JDK ([JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/)) or best [yourkit](https://www.yourkit.com/) to identify where you're loosing time ?